# How to use Javascript Autocomplete with Arabic?

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, arabic

I have a text box on a page with auto complete/suggest functionality. The problem is that it is on Arabic and once the format of the word changes, it does not suggest correct matching phrases. For example if I type "ل" in the text box, it will suggest all the words with "ل" in its single form but it will not suggest words/phrases where "ل" is present in one of the joining forms (for example it will not suggest "لاهور").

Answer (score 1):

The standard autocomplete uses substring which isn't useful for languages where a character can change when used in some context (like in Arabic).

I'm not aware of a web framework that handles this case.

You will need to write your own autocomplete code.